# Where does my footer go

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a site with Bootstrap and now I'm facing this problem that the footer that I just created does not show up at all somehow!

Here's the footer html codes:

```
<div class="footer">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="topfooter">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 socails">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middlefooter">
                        <div class="row BKoodakBold">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <h1 class="footerTitle">واحد امور مالی</h1>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <h1 class="footerTitle">واحد امور مالی</h1>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <h1 class="footerTitle">واحد امور مالی</h1>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <h1 class="footerTitle">واحد امور مالی</h1>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                                <a class="footerPara">پیگیری سفارش</a></br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottomfooter">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-10 socails">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the result I get, is this:

[print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYVSt.png)

So as you can see it does not show up correctly! And this is also the css for this footer:

```
    .footer{
    height:400px;
    background-color:black;
}

.socials{

}
.socials ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
.socials ul li {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.footerTitle{
    font-size:20px;
}
.footerPara{
    padding-right:3px;
}
.footerPara, .footerTitle{
    text-align:right;
    color:#fff;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong ? Why it does not appear correctly ?

Not that my footer is inside of a `div` with id of `content` with this settings:

```
#content{
background-color:black;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:550px;
background:#ebebeb;
height:3800px;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

Comment: It's probably this `top:550px;` - although there are much better ways to style and maintain a footer than absolute positioning

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning for your content? It's very likely that you don't need to do this. Let your content dictate the page height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the height of `#content`. Try changing `height: 3800px` to `height: auto` an see if that works.

The problem is that when you specified height with `overflow: hidden` you have limited space for content, extra content will be hidden.

Also your `#content` has duplicated background color, you probably want only one of this two `background-color: black` and `background: #ebebeb`.